# Flap on low profile Tyre - Can this be fixed

Tags: tires, repair

I hit a pothole as I was going round a corner at about 30mph, didn’t think much of it at the time, but when I got home I saw this crack/flap in the tyre, I have only recently got this tyre and have only done around 200 miles on it

(https://ibb.co/fxt6Ny)

Comment: Keep driving and keep an eye on it. Does not appear to be dangerous.

Comment: Is it worth using a rubber adhesive glue to stick it back together?

Comment: I would cut it off.

Comment: How deep is the flap? If it's not deep, either cut it off or throw some Shoe-glue at it.